# Stripe-iOS backend method in Django to create ephemeral key?

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, stripe-payments

I've been following [Standard iOS Integration Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard) of Stripe for my iOS app, which uses a backend written in Python-Django, to issue an ephemeral key.

This is the function I came up with in my views.py:

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "sk_test_Xf1yJ9qESRcCliM9iLoRmCIW"

def issue_key(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        api_version = request.POST.get('api_version')
        customerId = request.session['customerId']
        key = stripe.EphemeralKey.create(customer=customerId, api_version=api_version)
        return JsonResponse({'key': key})
    else:
        return redirect("home:feed")
```

In my iOS app, I copied all the files from [stripe-ios Standard Integration](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)) and filled in **stripePublishableKey** and **backendBaseURL** accordingly.

I'm also successfully creating a Stripe customer when a new user registers to my app, through Firebase Cloud Functions.

However, when **CheckoutViewController** loads, I get "Response status code was unacceptable: 404" error.

Assuming this error occurs while returning a JSON response from my backend, what is the correct code for the above method? Or am I missing something else on the Swift side?

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You really shouldn't share secret keys on any public forum. Even if they are test keys.

As for your issue, you should try to add more logging in your backend to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Paul. You are right about the secret key, but the key above is not the real one. I debugged further and the call doesn't hit my backend server: **issue_key()** doesn't run when **CheckoutViewController** loads. My backend base URL is http://steerr.com/issue-key/. Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like a routing problem. I'd check your backend framework and make sure that you've set it up correctly. As for the secret key, even a test key is dangerous to have in public as it allows malicious people to mess with your test data. If I were you I'd edit your question and remove the key entirely.